# Linking two users as partners for a mobile application

Tags: android, flutter, mobile-application, flutter-android

I am designing a flutter android application, for which I want functionality where a user can invite their partner (another application user) through some invite/partner code that will link their account together so that they can message each other, and get notifications about each others activities and stuff. If someone can please guide me/point me in to correct direction for this?
Thanks a ton for your time!

Comment: your question is good but StackOverflow is not the platform for this kind of question. I will suggest you join flutter discord or slack community where you will get the answer to the question.

Comment: You need to plan your not only app but backend system too to support this functionality. And backend has major role in this.

Comment: as @ᴅᴇʙᴊᴇᴇᴛ mentioned, Stackoverflow is not the platform for such questions. You can raise a question like these in Reddit, or LinkedIn etc.

Comment: @Amit here is the official discord server of flutter community https://discord.gg/TN5xuQ4x

Comment: Thanks a lot, @ᴅᴇʙᴊᴇᴇᴛ. Will try poking around on discord too

Comment: Thank you @PriyankaRawat, and yes I'm focusing on designing the backend as it will play a major role for this functionality but was hoping for any hint/guidance/blog or anything that can help me even a tiny bit. But thanks!

Comment: I can try to explain, You need to keep relation of user A with Other users of app in a table. Using same table you can list out related users to A via api on App. Now it totally depends on your requirement that how do you want to Invite with a InviteCode.

Comment: @PriyankaRawat that does make sense, will try to continue on this path! Thank you very much!